# Why does Postman ignore the protocol and port nr in variables?

Tags: postman

Postman ignores the protocol and port nr in a variable:

I have a host variable set up to contain a custom port:

[image]

When I try to use the variable, it doesn't contain protocol nor port:
[image]

Do I have to do something special to have the protocol and port nr remembered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The variable you add is in collection while the value is from environment: Read about scope and precedence of variables . Delete environment variable to get value from collection variable. 'E' indicate that value is coming from environment , if no environment then it will show as 'C' meaning collection

https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/#variable-scopes

[image]

### In postman **precedence** is from down to bottom and **scope** is from top to bottom

**Scope:**

Meaning if you have global variable defined then it will be visible for all collections and environment variable will be visible only for that particular environment.

**Precedence**

if you have a variable with same name defined in both environment and collection then the value will be taken from **environment**. as precedence is collection < environment

Comment: Thanks PDHide, I've got it working now :)

Comment: please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign @)

Answer (score 1):

Is there another host variable set ? As that one shows scope Environment in the second screenshot and the first screenshot shows it set at collection scope. Try to rename the host variable for the collection to something else and then try to call it in the same collection and see what it shows.
Verification
On both the postman Linux and Web client, setting a collection variable called  host like yours showed the protocol and port on calls within that collection.

Comment: Thanks Roland, I've got it working now :)